# How to Secure Restlet Resources Through Spring oauth2?

Tags: spring, security, restlet

I am using Spring security with oauth2. I want to Know how can secure my restlet resources through this .

I have done the following configurations

**web.xml**

```
  ----
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/test2.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>   
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> 
 -----
```

**The spring configuration**

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd"> 
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
    authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
        parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>
<!-- The OAuth2 protected resources are separated out into their own block 
    so we can deal with authorization and error handling separately. This isn't 
    mandatory, but it makes it easier to control the behaviour. -->

<http pattern="/api/streams/*" create-session="never"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/streams/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="/api/streams/*" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="/api/streams/*" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />
<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>
<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
 <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
     <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</authentication-manager>
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service id="userDetailsService">
            <user name="user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
  class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
     <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>
<!-- Used for the persistenceof tokens (currently an in memory implementation) -->
<bean id="tokenStore"
class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />
<!-- Used to create token and and every thing about them except for their 
    persistence that is reposibility of TokenStore (Given here is a default implementation) -->
<bean id="tokenServices"
class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>
<bean id="userApprovalHandler"
class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
</bean>
<!-- authorization-server aka AuthorizationServerTokenServices is an interface 
    that defines everything necessary for token management -->
<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
    user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
    resource-id="/api/streams/*" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<!-- ClientsDeailsService: Entry Point to clients database (given is in 
    memory implementation) -->
<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
    <!-- client -->
    <oauth:client client-id="clentid"
        authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,client_credentials"
        authorities="ROLE_USER" scope="read,write,trust" secret="secret" />
    <oauth:client client-id="my-trusted-client-with-secret"
        authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
        secret="somesecret" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
</oauth:client-details-service>
<sec:global-method-security
    pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    <!--you could also wire in the expression handler up at the layer of the 
        http filters. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1452 -->
    <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security>
<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
</beans>
```

**Spring mvc**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org  
/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd"> 
   <mvc:annotation-driven/> 
</beans>
```

**Java Resouce class**

```
public class myResources extends ServerResource {    
@Get()
public Representation requestGet() {


    System.out.println("==========call reached====================");
 }
```

> **Toke API     : http://myexample.com:8080/Test/oauth
>                /token?grant_type=password&client_id=clentid&client_secret=secret&
>
>                username=user&password=password**
>
> **Resource API :http://myexample.com:8080/Test/api/streams/userAgents
>                 /useragent_1/content.json?access_token=1559baa2-7e67-4d44-b1eb-4c9a2eaee621**

My resource API's as attached to restlet router . I have successfully generated the token . But when i cann my resource api with this token no content responce comes . Why  this happens ? Is there any problem with xml configurations . Please suggest a solution .

Comment: What http status code do you get ? 

Try to send the token in the header     

 Authorisation : "Bearer 1559baa2-7e67-4d44-b1eb-4c9a2eaee621"